# remove a class element

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to remove a class that has been appended to a div id? Earlier I appended a star to a label,when a checkbox is click.

```
 $("<span class='req'><em> * </em></span>").appendTo("#displayPanel #labelstr"+div_id);
```

Now,if the same checkbox is clicked again I want to remove that star.
I know there is a remove() option, but what is the proper code for it?
Please guide me.

Comment: Looks like jQuery to me. Tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the looks of it, you're not trying to remove a class which would be the [`removeClass()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/removeClass) command, but instead need to remove a child element from a `<div>`

You could do

```
$("#displayPanel #labelstr" + div_id + " span.req").remove();
```

to remove the child span element with class 'req' from the `<div>`.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is exactly what I said, as the OP seems to have misphrased his question.

Comment: ya you are right. I did it wrongly. Instead using $("#labelstr" + div_id + " span.req").remove(); as suggested by you and everyone else.Thank you.Just one id was enough,so I left out that #labelstr.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use 2 id selectors as they 'should' be unique, so just do

```
$("#labelstr" + div_id + " span.req").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess:

```
$('#displayPanel #labelstr'+div_id+' .req').remove();
```

if you want to remove the .req and only have one of them per element.

Comment: ya you are right. I did it wrongly. Instead using $("#labelstr" + div_id + " span.req").remove(); as suggested by you and everyone else.Thank you.Just one id was enough,so I left out that #labelstr.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer. It is

```
   $('.req').remove();
```

Earlier I tried the same,without the quotes, that is why I didn't get the required result.

@machine: Yes,it is jQuery. Thank you.

Comment: But that will remove all elements that have a class or req. Are you sure you want this? Also just using a class in a selector is slow. It is better to use nodeName.class for performance especially on a large dom

Comment: yes, i was wrong. It removed for all the elements that have that class.
Instead using $("#labelstr" + div_id + " span.req").remove();
as suggested by you and everyone else. Thank you.